# jquery setTimeout browser change tab stops the animation

Tags: jquery, html, svg

I'm creating a simple clock with  and jQuery.

I'm using the `setTimeout(rotate_seconds, 1000);` to animate the rotation seconds hand.

it works pretty well, but if I change tab in the browser, the animation stops and when I go back to the clock tab the animation continues from where I left it.

How can I fix this problem? Maybe I should ignore the tab-change

Thanks

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? As I read in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955455/jquery-animate-stop-when-i-change-the-browser-tab?rq=1) question the problem is solved in version 1.6.3 and higher.

Comment: I'm including this:
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js

I don't know how but I've just fixed the problem!
I was calling the function for the first time with another setTimeout. Whithout that call it seems working pretty well but I don't know why!